# Find hyperlinks of a page in python without BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

What I am trying to do is find all the hyper links of a web page here is what I have so far but it does not work

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

def findHyperLinks(webpage):
    link = "Not found"
    encoding = "utf-8"
    for webpagesline in webpage:
        webpagesline = str(webpagesline, encoding)
        if "<a href>" in webpagesline:
            indexstart = webpagesline.find("<a href>")
            indexend = webpagesline.find("</a>")
            link = webpagesline[indexstart+7:indexend]
            return link
    return link

def main():
    address = input("Please enter the adress of webpage to find the hyperlinks")
    try:
        webpage = urlopen(address)
        link =  findHyperLinks(webpage)
        print("The hyperlinks are", link)

        webpage.close()
    except Exception as exceptObj:
        print("Error:" , str(exceptObj))

main()
```

Comment: Open a web browser, navigate to a page, and right-click, view source. Then Ctrl+F and search for `<a href>`. That's one of your problems.

Comment: no I can only use url open  we haven't  discuss xpath in class yet

Comment: How about regular expressions?

Comment: I'm not really sure what that is the professor in class gave us this as an example guide but instead of finding the hyperlink he showed us how to find the tittle of the page which is   different <tittle></tittle>

Comment: @JonathonReinhart it does not show anything when I do that

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I kinda get it now but if I'm trying to find a something like this <a href="//stackoverflow.com">current community</a>  how can I do it

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple problems in your code. One of them is that you are trying to find links with present, empty and the only one `href` attribute: `<a href>`.

Anyway, if you would use an *HTML parser* (well, to parse HTML), things would get much more easy and reliable.  Example using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(address))
for link in soup.find_all("a", href=True):
    print(link["href"], link.get_text())
```

Comment: I am not allow to use BeautifulSoup in this code

Answer (score 2):

Without BeautifulSoap you can use RegExp and simple function.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import re

def find_link(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    res = str(response.read())
    my_dict = re.findall('(?<=<a href=")[^"]*', res)

    for x in my_dict:
        # simple skip page bookmarks, like #about
        if x[0] == '#':
            continue

        # simple control absolute url, like /about.html
        # also be careful with redirects and add more flexible
        # processing, if needed
        if x[0] == '/':
            x = url + x

        print(x)

find_link('http://cnn.com')
```

Comment: thanks this actually helped